# jQuery Cycle plugin pager errors

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I am attempting a single input of jquery Cycle to control 4 different cycles across the website. They have all got different ID tags, however, the pager control div appears 4 times. Here is my jquery:

```
$('#homeslide, #hairslide, #panamaslide, #chawtonsslide') 
.cycle({ 
fx: 'fade', 
speed: '1000', 
timeout: '8000', 
next: '#next',
prev: '#prev',
cleartypeNoBg: 'true',
pager: '#controls'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner-container">
    <div id="prev"></div>
    <div id="next"></div>
    <div id="controls"></div>
    <div id="homeslide">
        <img src="template/banner1.jpg" alt="Banner Image 1" />
        <img src="template/banner2.jpg" alt="Banner Image 2" />
        <img src="template/banner3.jpg" alt="Banner Image 3" />
        <img src="template/banner4.jpg" alt="Banner Image 4" />
        <img src="template/banner5.jpg" alt="Banner Image 5" />
        <img src="template/banner6.jpg" alt="Banner Image 6" />
        <img src="template/banner7.jpg" alt="Banner Image 7" />
    </div>
    <div id="hairslide">
        <img src="template/banner2.jpg" alt="Banner Image 1" />
        <img src="template/banner2.jpg" alt="Banner Image 2" />
        <img src="template/banner3.jpg" alt="Banner Image 3" />
        <img src="template/banner4.jpg" alt="Banner Image 4" />
        <img src="template/banner5.jpg" alt="Banner Image 5" />
        <img src="template/banner6.jpg" alt="Banner Image 6" />
        <img src="template/banner7.jpg" alt="Banner Image 7" />
    </div>
    <div id="panamaslide">
        <img src="template/banner2.jpg" alt="Banner Image 1" />
        <img src="template/banner2.jpg" alt="Banner Image 2" />
        <img src="template/banner3.jpg" alt="Banner Image 3" />
        <img src="template/banner4.jpg" alt="Banner Image 4" />
        <img src="template/banner5.jpg" alt="Banner Image 5" />
        <img src="template/banner6.jpg" alt="Banner Image 6" />
        <img src="template/banner7.jpg" alt="Banner Image 7" />
    </div>
    <div id="chawtonsslide">
        <img src="template/banner2.jpg" alt="Banner Image 1" />
        <img src="template/banner2.jpg" alt="Banner Image 2" />
        <img src="template/banner3.jpg" alt="Banner Image 3" />
        <img src="template/banner4.jpg" alt="Banner Image 4" />
        <img src="template/banner5.jpg" alt="Banner Image 5" />
        <img src="template/banner6.jpg" alt="Banner Image 6" />
        <img src="template/banner7.jpg" alt="Banner Image 7" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

It works, apart from showing 4 pager divs. I was going to try a $.each count but as they all need IDs i dont think i can do that. Its worth noting that these different blocks of images are controlled via our CMS and only certain ones are shown per page. Example: home.htm shows #homeslide only

Thanks guys

Comment: Unfortunately it's for a client at work and i can't post the link. I'll try and grab some code and post it, 2 secs

Comment: added as much as i could

Comment: so you only want 1 pager control for all of them? or no pager control?

Comment: one pager control to show only, as you can see there's 4 haha.

Comment: so there are 4 pages, each rendering other div cycle ? and you want on each page exactly one cycle and exactly one pager ?

Comment: yeah, i've got the right slideshow showing, just it keeps adding all the pagers into one, instead of using one pager and appending the right amount of <a> tags based on the current slideshow, its adding them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#homeslide') 
    .cycle({ 
    fx: 'scrollVert', 
    speed: '1000', 
    timeout: '8000', 
    pager: '#pager',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i) {
            return '<a href="#"></a>';
    },
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev',
    cleartypeNoBg: 'true'
});

$('#hairslide') // can add other divs here that require to use the same pager
    .cycle({ 
    fx: 'fade', 
    speed: '1000', 
    timeout: '8000',
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev',
    pager: '#pager',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i) {
            return $('#pager a:eq('+i+')');
    },
    cleartypeNoBg: 'true',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use .each() function to dynamically add pager controls to each cycle.

```
$.each( $('#homeslide, #hairslide, #panamaslide, #chawtonsslide'), function(i, e){
    $(e).before('<div id="nav' + i + '">').cycle({
        // other options here
        pager:  '#nav' + i
    });
});
```

Comment: This also just breaks everything. It kills all the jquery code. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a 'slideshow' class to each slideshow than calling each like based on the class,
so you can keep your id's

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager-double.html

Comment: Tried this, it just breaks everything :( I think it's because the div has an id and class together. It makes no sense, but i need both lol

Comment: Also, some of the divs have different amounts of images in, so the dots at the bottom would be different each page. Im so confused